# Parse a text file into instances of a class based on keywords c#

Tags: c#, file, parsing, text

I have a text file that contains a list of points:

> POINT:
>    TYPE 5, 
>    OBJECT ID 2, 
>    DEVICE TYPE CAT, 
>    TAG 'ADDRESS-1',
>    DESCRIPTION 'kitty', 
>    UNITS 'Lb',
>
> POINT:
>    TYPE 5,
>    OBJECT ID 2,
>    DEVICE TYPE CAT, 
>    TAG 'ADDRESS-2', 
>    DESCRIPTION 'orange kitty', 
>    UNITS 'Lb',
>
> POINT:
>    TYPE 2,
>    OBJECT ID 3,
>    DEVICE TYPE DOG, 
>    TAG 'ADDRESS-5', 
>    DESCRIPTION 'brown dog', 
>    UNITS 'Lb',

From this, I want to create instances (in this case, 2) of my class 'Cat' that contain the tag and description in this text file(and then put them in a list of Cats). I only want to take the description and tag from points of Type 5 (those are the cats).

I'm not sure what the best approach is to get the strings I want. I need to search the entire file for all points of type 5, then for each of those points, take the description and tag and add it to a new Cat.

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        string line;
        List<Cat> catList = new List<Cat>();
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Config\pets.txt");
        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] words = line.Split(',');
            catList.Add(new Cat cat1)
        }}
```

I ended up doing it this way:

```
 public static List<List<string>> Parse()
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Config\pets.txt";
        string readText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "POINT:" }; //POINT is the keyword the text will be split on
        string[] result;


        result = readText.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        List<List<string>> catData = new List<List<string>>();
        //split the text into an list of pieces
        List<string> tags = new List<string>(); //tags go here
        List<string> descriptions = new List<string>(); //descriptions go here
        foreach (string s in result)
        {
            if (s.Contains("TYPE 5")) //TYPE 5 = CAT
            {

                string[] parts = s.Split(','); //split the cat by commas
                string chop = "'"; //once tags and descriptions have been found, only want to keep what is inside single quotes ie 'orange kitty'
                foreach (string part in parts)
                {
                    if (part.Contains("TAG"))
                    {
                        int startIndex = part.IndexOf(chop);
                        int endIndex = part.LastIndexOf(chop);
                        int length = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
                        string path = part.Substring(startIndex, length);
                        tag = tag.Replace(chop, string.Empty);
                        tags.Add(tag);
                        //need to create instance of Cat with this tag
                    }
                    if (part.Contains("DESCRIPTION"))
                    {
                        int startIndex = part.IndexOf(chop);
                        int endIndex = part.LastIndexOf(chop);
                        int length = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
                        string description = part.Substring(startIndex, length);
                        description = description.Replace(chop, string.Empty);
                        descriptions.Add(description);
                        //need to add description to Cat instance that matches associated tag
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        catData.Add(tags);
        catData.Add(descriptions);
        return catData;
```

Comment: Read the file line by line, parse the line and create an instance of your class, then add it to a list. Start to work and then ask if you have problems on the code you have written

Comment: what do you have so far? do you have code that reads the file? do you have a class that represents the object you want to populate? show us the relevant code!

Comment: For string parsing, you could use Regex. If you're not handy with that, it looks simple enough to just parse manually, looking for keywords and commas.

Comment: Added my most recent attempt. I want to split the file by keyword 'point', not a character - the trouble is I don't see any one character I could split by. Is there another way to divide a file into smaller chunks I could then parse?

Comment: That's a start. Now look at the first entry in words and if it matches the searched text take the fourth and fifth entry, remove the unwanted parts (TAG/DESCRIPTION) and, with the remainder, set the properties of the Cat class

Comment: Without seeing more of the text file I'm not sure you will get the results you are looking for.  I've been parsing text files for 40 years and have often seeing posting like this fail until more of the text file is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create a class that represents the fields you want to capture. For this example, I'm capturing all the fields, but you can customize it how you want. I called this class "Animal", since it seems the "points" represent an animal.

Then I would add a static `Parse` method to the class that will return an instance of an `Animal` based on some input string. This method will parse the input string and attempt to set the relevant properties of the `Animal` object based on the values in the string.

I also added a `ToString()` override on the class so we have some way of displaying the output:

```
class Animal
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses an input string and returns an Animal based
    /// on any property values found in the string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The string to parse for property values</param>
    /// <returns>An animal instance with specified properties</returns>
    public static Animal Parse(string input)
    {
        var result = new Animal();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return result;

        // Parse input string and set fields accordingly
        var keyValueParts = input
            .Split(new [] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(kvp => kvp.Trim());

        foreach (var keyValuePart in keyValueParts)
        {
            if (keyValuePart.StartsWith("Type", 
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                int type;
                var value = keyValuePart.Substring("Type".Length).Trim();
                if (int.TryParse(value, out type))
                {
                    result.Type = type;
                }
            }
            else if (keyValuePart.StartsWith("Object Id", 
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                int objectId;
                var value = keyValuePart.Substring("Object Id".Length).Trim();
                if (int.TryParse(value, out objectId))
                {
                    result.ObjectId = objectId;
                }
            }
            else if (keyValuePart.StartsWith("Device Type", 
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var value = keyValuePart.Substring("Device Type".Length).Trim();
                result.DeviceType = value;
            }
            else if (keyValuePart.StartsWith("Tag", 
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var value = keyValuePart.Substring("Tag".Length).Trim();
                result.Tag = value;
            }
            else if (keyValuePart.StartsWith("Description", 
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var value = keyValuePart.Substring("Description".Length).Trim();
                result.Description = value;
            }
            else if (keyValuePart.StartsWith("Units", 
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var value = keyValuePart.Substring("Units".Length).Trim();
                result.Units = value;
            }
        }

        return result;            
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Return a string that describes this animal
        var animalProperties = new StringBuilder();
        animalProperties.Append($"Type = {Type}, Object Id = {ObjectId}, ");
        animalProperties.Append($"Device Type = {DeviceType}, Tag = {Tag}, ");
        animalProperties.Append($"Description = {Description}, Units = {Units}");
        return animalProperties.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now that we have an object that can create itself from a string, we just need to read in the file contents, split it on the "Point:" keyword, and then pass each string to the `Animal` class to get our instances.

I added some `System.Linq` clause to filter on animals that have `Type = 5` (which you said are all cats), since you said that was the only animal you were interested in. Of course you could remove this to get all animals, or replace it with "Dog" to get the dogs, etc..:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.txt";

    // Read all file contents and split it on the word "Point:"
    var fileContents = Regex
        .Split(File.ReadAllText(filePath), "Point:", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        .Where(point => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(point))
        .Select(point => point.Trim());

    // Get all animals that are cats from the results
    var catList = fileContents
        .Select(Animal.Parse)
        .Where(animal => animal.Type == 5)
        .ToList();

    // Output results
    catList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    // Wait for input before closing
    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I ended up doing a line-by-line parse, but your strategy is certainly more elegant! Thanks for the help. I added what I came up with yesterday to my question if you're interested - but I think I'll probably be changing it up!